# Hugo database of tags?

Tags: taxonomy, image-gallery, hugo

I have just started using Hugo. Suppose I want several galleries, classified by certain tags, so that the corresponding sets of images are not necessarily disjoint. Or in other words, I want to go to the trouble of adding tags to each image. Rather than making a separate .md file for each image, which would rapidly become unwieldly, is it possible to have a single file containing the image file names and their tag (I have in mind a database or something similar)?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but [data templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/) might be useful.